# How to serialize some nested relational models in django using DRF?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-orm, django-serializer

I have some Django models with different relations to each other — `Many-to-many`, and `Foreignkey`. By that means, I want to serialize them using `djnago-rest`.

Here are the models:

```py
class CommonFieldsAbstract(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)

class ServerModel(CommonFieldsAbstract):
    server_ip = models.GenericIPAddressField(default='172.17.0.1')
    server_port = models.IntegerField(default='9001')

class SNMPLineModel(CommonFieldsAbstract):
    ip_address = models.GenericIPAddressField()
    port = models.IntegerField(default=161)

class SNMPModel(CommonFieldsAbstract):  # target
    line = models.ForeignKey(SNMPLineModel, on_delete=CASCADE)
    servers = models.ManyToManyField(ServerModel)

class MetaDataModel(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    snmp_device = models.ForeignKey(SNMPModel, on_delete=CASCADE)
```

Before, I used to use the following approach to create the JSON manually:

```py
def meta_data_json(meta_data):
    meta_data_list = []
    for meta in meta_data:
        meta_data_list.append({
            meta.key: meta.value
        })
    return meta_data_list

def server_json(servers):
    return [{'ip': server.server_ip,
             'port': server.server_port}
            for server in servers]

def create_json():
    snmp = SNMPModel.objects.filter(name__contains='a-name')
    return {
        'name': snmp.name,
        'address': snmp.line.ip_address,
        'port': snmp.line.port,
        'servers': server_json(snmp.servers.all()),
        'meta_data': meta_data_json(MetaDataModel.objects.filter(
                snmp_device=snmp.pk
            )
        ),
        'device_pk': snmp.pk
    }
```

---

### My Question:

Now, how can I create such an above json via `django-rest-framework` instead?

I don't have any problem with many-to-many fields. In fact, my problem is the `foreignkey`(s).

Here's what I've done so far:

```py
# serializers.py

from rest_framework import serializers

class MetaDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = [
            'id',
            'key',
            'value',
            ]
        model = MetaDataModel

class ServerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = [
            'id',
            'server_ip',
            'server_port',
            ]
        model = ServerModel

class LineSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    port = serializers.RelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
        model = SNMPLineModel

class SNMPSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    servers = ServerSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)  # It is ok
    meta_data = MetaDataSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)  # It's not ok
    line = LineSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)  # It's not ok
    address = serializers.CharField(source=SNMPLineModel.ip_address)  # It's not ok
    port = serializers.CharField(source=SNMPLineModel.port)  # It's not ok

    class Meta:
        fields = [
            'id',
            'servers',
            'name',
            'address',
            'port',
            'line',
            'meta_data'
            ]
        model = SNMPModel
```

```py
# views.py

from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse

@csrf_exempt
def snippet_detail(request, name):
    try:
        snmp_conf = SNMPModel.objects.filter(name__contains=name)
    except SNMPModel.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse(status=404)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer = SNMPSerializer(snmp_conf, many=True)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=200, safe=False)
```

```py
# urls.py

from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('snippets/<name>/', views.snippet_detail)
]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `serializers.SerializerMethodField()` is a useful method to add in relations like this.
`get_meta_data()` is a bit of magic evaluating the fieldname to call the method.

Address and port seem to be a simple relation and `line.FOO` should work.

```
class SNMPSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    servers = ServerSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)  # It is ok
    meta_data = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    line = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    address = serializers.CharField(source="line.ip_address", read_only=True)
    port = serializers.CharField(source="line.port" , read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        fields = ['id', 'servers', 'name', 'address', 'port', 'line', 'meta_data']
        model = SNMPModel

    def get_meta_data(self, instance):
        metadatamodels = MetaDataModel.objects.filter(snmp_device=instance)
        serializer = MetaDataSerializer(instance=metadatamodels, many=True, read_only=True)

        return serializer.data

    def get_line(self, instance):
        serializer = LineSerializer(instance.line, read_only=True)

        return serializer.data
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'm trying with your code snippet. But I'm bit confiused about `"line.port"` did you mean `"SNMPLineModel.port"`?

Comment: I think of if like `instance.line.port`  but DRF does not need us to specify  `instance`.

Comment: How can I solve this error: `TypeError: 'SNMPLineModel' object is not iterable` caused by this line in `get_line()` method:  `return serializer.data`

Comment: ahh, that should be a queryset `instance=instance.line` ?

Comment: I solved that by removing `many=True`, I mean: `serializer = LineSerializer(instance.line, read_only=True)`

Answer (score 0):

For solving the mentioned problems I did the following solutions:

1. For a Forward Foreignkey you do not need `many=True`
2. For a Reverse Foreignkey you need using `related-model_set` while you haven't defined `related_name`.
3. For an extra field you just need the exact queryset.

Therefore, I reached the following code snippet without using `.SerializerMethodField()` as Michael used on his answer:

```py
class SNMPSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    servers = ServerSerializer(many=True)
    meta_data = MetaDataSerializer(many=True, source="metadatamodel_set")
    line = LineSerializer()
    address = serializers.CharField(source="line.ip_address")
    port = serializers.CharField(source="line.port")

    class Meta:
        fields = (
            "id",
            "servers",
            "name",
            "address",
            "port",
            "line",
            "meta_data",
        )
        model = SNMPModel
```